# Measures of expanding maps of the circle and their coding

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

It is well known that the dynamics of linear examples $f(x)=mx(mod1)$ for natural $m\geq 2$ is semi conjugated to the full shift on the space of one-sided sequences of digits $\{0,…,m−1\}.$ Is it true that the semi conjugated map measures theoretical isomorphism for all measures? If not, under what (minimum assumption on maps) that is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minimal assumption on what?

Comment: @JohnB : either on  the expanding map or the shift map

Comment: Is this assigned home work (so hints are preferable) or just for general knowledge?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh : Just for general knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by noting the obvious:

**The semiconjugacy is not a conjugacy because there are points with more than one coding.**

For example, for $m=2$ these are the points in $[0,1]$ having a base-$2$ representation with infinitely many consecutive $1$'s. Note that all of them are of the form $k/2^n$ for some integers $k$ and $n$. They form a Borel set.

**So you obtain an isomorphism if and only if this Borel set has measure zero.**

Continuing the example, since the set is countable, it has zero Lebesgue measure. So Lebesgue measure induces a measure on the shift (in this case the Bernoulli measure with probabilities $1/2$, $1/2$) for which we have an isomorphism.

You can make a similar reasoning for any $m$.

Answer (score -1):

To talk about a measure theoretic isomorphism you first need measures on both spaces.  The most classic example is if you give $[0,1]$ Lebesgue measure and give sequence space $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ the infinite product of the uniform measure on $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$.  In this case the semiconjugacy map is a measure theoretic isomorphism between the two systems.  There are also many other choices of measures you can do this with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there such a statement that is true for all measures? I meant the semiconjugacy map is a measure theoretic isomorphism between the two systems for all measures.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that.  If you take any shift-invariant measure on the sequence space $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, then you push that measure forward to $[0,1]$ by the conjugacy map, and then you have another measure theoretic isomorphism between the two systems.  And vice versa (you can take any $(\times m)$-invariant measure on $[0,1]$ and push it forward to sequence space)